# Wordpress class.wp-scripts.php comments out CDATA instead of just removing them

Tags: ajax, wordpress, cdata, inspectlet

I'm using wp_localize_script to pass some variables from PHP to client side javascript.  This function ends up calling another function that does this:

```
function print_extra_script( $handle, $echo = true ) {
    if ( !$output = $this->get_data( $handle, 'data' ) )
        return;

    if ( !$echo )
        return $output;

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n"; // CDATA and type='text/javascript' is not needed for HTML 5
    echo "/* <![CDATA[ */\n";
    echo "$output\n";
    echo "/* ]]> */\n";
    echo "</script>\n";

    return true;
}
```

Now what is the point of commenting out those CDATA tags, why not just remove them?
This is breaking [inspectlet](https://www.inspectlet.com/) because it is getting screwed up by those extra comments around the CDATA tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I guess, because although `CDATA` is not needed in HTML5, WordPress devs are still including it for blogs and websites, where HTML4 or XHTML is used, because in nearly every case it doesn't do harm.
I'm looking for a solution myself as I want to get rid of the --in HTML5-- unnecessary `type="text/javascript"` attribute.

My best guess so far is, to extend `class WP_Scripts` from `wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php`
But I'm still researching on how to best accomplish that.